# How to Install sSMTP on CentOS 8 AppStream

Tags: centos, ssmtp

I have used the [sSMTP](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/ssmtp) package on CentOS 7 to send root emails to my Gmail address using an external mail server.

However, the package isn't officially available for CentOS 8 in the EPEL 8 repo.
Can it be installed on this OS like installing from the source?

I assume that the source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/ajwans/sSMTP).

I'm a novice about Linux so if it is possible then clear step-by-step instructions would be most helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Find the package in Fedora and install it

Comment: @RomeoNinov Fedora doesn't have the package in the specific repo (EPEL 8). Did you check the first link provided in the question?

Comment: Rajan, you are extremely lazy. From link you provide I see this page: https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=2028713 and in this page this link: https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/ssmtp/2.64/30.fc37/x86_64/ssmtp-2.64-30.fc37.x86_64.rpm of RPM file with the package

Comment: @RomeoNinov It is not that I'm lazy. It is, that I'm lacking enough knowledge about These Linux topics. BTW I have posted an answer. Maybe you could have helpful feedback, then welcome to reply, and thanks for the directional comments above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially didn't know that the `DNF` or `YUM` command could be used to install a package from the direct RPM URL/download. I have previously used `yum install <package_name>` command to install them from the repo.

As @RomeoNinov guided in the comment, I tried to install directly from the RPM path as shown. But the `GLIBC` version in my OS is 2.28 instead of 2.34.

```
dnf install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/ssmtp/2.64/30.fc37/x86_64/ssmtp-2.64-30.fc37.x86_64.rpm

Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) needed by ssmtp-2.64-30.fc37.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

yum list glibc
varnishcache_varnish64                          287  B/s | 833  B     00:02
varnishcache_varnish64-source                   307  B/s | 833  B     00:02
Installed Packages
glibc.x86_64                        2.28-208.el8                         @baseos
Available Packages
glibc.i686                          2.28-209.el8                         baseos
glibc.x86_64                        2.28-209.el8                         baseos


dnf install --nobest ssmtp-2.64-30.fc37.x86_64.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:32 ago on Fri 19 Aug 2022 02:51:55 AM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) needed by ssmtp-2.64-30.fc37.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Then I decided to install the package from its RPM in EPEL 7 repo (the package isn't available in the EPEL 8 repo) and **that WORKED**.

```
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/s/ssmtp-2.64-14.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Maybe it is possible to compile/build from the latest source/RPM.
However, at present, I'm lacking enough knowledge about it.

Comment: Try to install older version of a package to satisfy the GLIB requirement

Comment: I already did that, and that worked so posted the answer.